# Image Handling in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm new to android and I'm stuck. I want to create an app (Picture Quiz) in which an image shown up with specific name under it in a textview. User will choose one answer and new image and its name comes, and they continously keep on coming until the user chooses the wrong answer. Then it will start again but this time images and their names should be shuffled.

I don't know where to put all these images (150 of them) either in drawables or somewhere else. How can i get and show both image and name using one ID and how can i shuffle them. Will i needed sqlite database?

Note: Sorry for lack of data and presentation. I didn't started it yet because i did not found any solutions yet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! 150 images is a lot of data, and I bet you'd like to have even more as time goes on. Storing them locally doesn't seem like a good idea. You might want to store all these images on an external resource, like [Firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage), and retrieve them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

one of the best way is
1.
store all images in drawable
2.
Make POJO file which contains all three id, path (R.drawable.image1), name
3.
use Arraylist to insert all data
4.
use Random to shuffle 
sure, it's working, will get back further for more.

Comment: Thankyou so much. So what what do you prefer? Should i use firebase or save them locally because my app is supposed to be offline.